# Ubuntu　テキストファイルの作成、参照、コピー、ペースト

Tags: ubuntu

1. zen.txtファイル作りたい
2. このコマンド（python3 -c "import this"）で表示されたメッセージを1.に貼り付けたい
3. どのように作るか分からない

Ubuntuで作ったものがどこで見れるのか教えてください。

Comment: コマンドライン(シェル上)で処理するのであれば `python3 -c "import this" > zen.txt`

Answer (score 1):

テキストの作成はテキストエディタを起動し、そこで入力します。
下記のおすすめテキストエディタを参考にしてください。
https://eng-entrance.com/free_texteditor_linux